# Firebase Realtime Database - Adding query to Axios GET request?

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, axios

In my React app I have an axios.get request looks like the following:

```
    axios.get('https://[app name here].firebaseio.com/shoppingCart.json')
```

And it returns everything from my 'shoppingCart' endpoint in Firebase Realtime Database:

[image]

If I wanted to only return records with an 'uid' of "asdf1" for example, how would I go about adding the appropriate query to my GET request, if possible?

I also tried following the documentation here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data (regarding filtering by a specified child key) and constructed the following request, but I'm getting a 400 bad request error.

```
axios.get('https://[app name here].firebaseio.com/shoppingCart.json?orderBy="uid"&equalTo="asdf1"')
```

Comment: At a first glance this looks fine to me. Are there any more details in the response body?

Comment: Well here's the error message when I logged it to the console: Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Comment: That looks like the axios message, not the body from the HTTP response. Another way to get the same: can you reproduce the problem with the URL call in a browser, so without any JavaScript code? If so, can you share that URL? If you're worried about leaking your actual database, you can create a new project just for sharing the 
URL, and delete that once the problem is solved.

Comment: Ok I called the URL in my browser, and got a different error message that seems like it might lead somewhere: Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"uid\", for path \"/shoppingCart\", to the rules

Comment: It works now! Just added the rules as indicated by the error message to my Firebase Realtime DB. Thank you for pointing out directly making the URL call via the browser!

Comment: I suspected as much. ;-) Good to hear you got it fixed. Wanna post a self-answer?

Answer (score 2):

Many thanks to user Frank van Puffelen for guiding me to the solution.

I made the URL call in question to the browser, and the error message I received told me that I needed to define 'uid' as my index in my Realtime Database rules for 'shoppingCart'.

[image]

After doing so, I was able to successfully receive a response from my URL call that was properly filtered by the 'uid' I passed in.

Comment: thanks for writing the answer, i din't get i had to add an index on my db! for future reference, if someone needs to use 2 keys (eg firstName, lastName), can be written with: `".indexOn": ["lastName", "firstName"]`