# Firebase GET request orderby 400 bad request

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, get, sql-order-by

For a get request, I am trying to user order by like below but always get a 400 bad request. Here, multiple users can have multiple blog posts each with a unique id like b1 in screenshot below. The long sequence of characters is the uid of a user under blogs. Each user has their own uid.

> `https://assignment-c3557-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/blogs.json?orderBy="createdAt"`

I followed the documentation here

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data

All I am doing is issuing a simple GET request in react js as follows:

```
const resp = await fetch(`https://assignment-c3557-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/blogs.json?orderBy="createdAt"``)
        const data = await resp.json()
        if(!resp.ok) { ... }
```

Below is the database single entry for schema reference [image]

Comment: can you show the full code?

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my [previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72826318/firebase-post-url-400-bad-request/72826825?noredirect=1#comment128646286_72826825), this URL is invalid:

```
https://assignment-c3557-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/blogs.json/orderBy="createdAt"
                                                                                     ^
```

The query portion of a URL starts with a `?` character.

```
https://assignment-c3557-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/blogs.json?orderBy="createdAt"
                                                                                     ^
```

Comment: In error I pasted the wrong url, I indeed tried with a ? only. I just edited my post to correct it. With the correct url (with ?) , I still get a 400 bad request

Answer (score 0):

> [Firebase Realtime Database - Adding query to Axios GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481288/firebase-realtime-database-adding-query-to-axios-get-request)

I followed the above similar issue resolution to solve my problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).